# How do i specify the encoder to be used by imageresizer.ImageJob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

am trying to use image resizer.ImageJob in my mvc 4 to crop and save image as it is being uploaded. here is my code.

```
`//create cropping point information using the nameValueCollections specified in the image;
                System.Drawing.PointF point1 = new SD.PointF(collectionsValues["x1Cords"], collectionsValues["y1Cords"]);
                System.Drawing.PointF point2 = new SD.PointF(collectionsValues["x2Cords"], collectionsValues["y2Cords"]);

                //Setup the resize settings
                var resizeSettings = new ResizeSettings();
                resizeSettings.CropXUnits = collectionsValues["widthOfSelection"];
                resizeSettings.CropYUnits = collectionsValues["heightOfSelection"];
                resizeSettings.Format = file.ContentType;
                resizeSettings.CropTopLeft = point1;
                resizeSettings.CropBottomRight = point2;
                resizeSettings.Mode = FitMode.Crop;      


                //construct the image and save it in the disk.
                ImageJob theProcessedImage = new ImageJob(file, imagePath, resizeSettings, true, false);
                theProcessedImage.CreateParentDirectory = true;                
                theProcessedImage.Build();
`
```

my problem is that i keep getting exception to specify the encoder to be used in processing the image. Whenever **theProcessedImage.Build()** is called. So how do i specify the encoder, i have installed the **nuget (Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.Wic)** package following the instruction i found on the imageresizing site

Comment: You should post the actual error message, or you're likely to get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

#### If it's asking for the encoder to use, you're likely asking it for an invalid output format, like "tiff" or "ico". `jpeg`, `png`, `gif`, and `webp` are currently the only valid output formats.

If it's asking for the *decoder*, not the encoder, then the source file type is probably not supported, or you don't have the [FreeImageDecoder plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/freeimage) installed.

Comment: Hi, computer linguist i have resolved the error i was asking about and can no longer access the error message, thanks for the help anyway and forget about down voting me

Comment: On a second thought the error i was getting was [ImageResizer.ImageProcessingException :: No image encoder was found for this request]. Maybe your answer will help another person as this kept me from coding on my merry way (yeah it's my first time of using the library.)